# Safari stop jquery animation when request link with download header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

sorry for my question if it has a trivial solution: i searched on web but i didn't find anything.

When i click on an href that link to an url with download header, safari stop all my jquery functions that animate css.

In my case, i have a php script that generate a big pdf file, it take a lot of seconds to complete task; to stop user interaction i open a modal with a progress bar.

On Chrome and firefox work fine, but safari when request this url with download header it stop my jquery functions, alert function works fine instead.

To fix this problem I manage event when the modal is shown and after i request the link

```
$('#pdf_download_button').click(function(){

$('#download_modal')
.on('shown.bs.modal', function() {

    location.href = "http://www.example.com/modules/myModules/include/pdf_generator.php";

}).modal('show');

var fileDownloadCheckTimer;
fileDownloadCheckTimer = window.setInterval(function (e) 
{
    if($.cookie('download_pdf'))
    {   
        window.clearInterval(fileDownloadCheckTimer);
        $.removeCookie('download_pdf') 
        $('#download_modal').modal('hide');         
    }
    else
    {   
    }      
}, 1000);
});
```

But if there is a way, i would  show the animation in modal made with jquery.

I hope this is not an old question.

Thank in advance
Marco

Comment: Why are you setting location.href?

Comment: because i need to call script that generate the big pdf file: this url response with pdf file ( header content disposition: attachment ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**

Going off what you told me in the comments, I updated the code and will include the HTML elements.

```html
<div class="btn-wrapper">
    <button class="btn btn-default" id="pdf_download_button">Download</button>
</div>

<div class="modal" id="download_modal">
    <div id="bar"></div>    
</div>
```

```js
//shown.bs.modal listener
$('#download_modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    $('#bar').animate({width: '100px'}, 5000, function () {
        //callback once animation is done
        $('#download_modal').modal('hide');
    });

    location.href = 'http://www.digilog.de/pub/blog/android_download_header_test.php/ctaos/cdafqZIP/';
});

//click listener
$('#pdf_download_button').click(function(){
  $('#download_modal').modal('show');
});
```

- I placed the `shown.bs.modal` event listener outside of the handler function for the `click` event.
- I removed the additional `.modal('show')` because from what I can tell, it's unnecessary to declare again after the initial `show`
- I am using an example url for the download link
- I close the modal within the `.animate()` callback
- I am running this in Safari 5.x and it works fine (downloads the zip file and animates the bar)
- Here is the example jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k8ALQ/5/

Comment: Sorry, the first $('#download_modal').modal('show'); there isn't in my code, i 'll edit now.

Comment: I test your code but jquery animation still not working.

Comment: Safari seems to block css animations when requesting an url

Comment: @Marco - What version of Safari are you checking with? What exactly (without specific url details) is the code you're using to animate?  What libraries are you using? These will help me understand and recreate what you're doing.

Comment: safari 7.0.4 (9537.76.4), i'm using TCPDF and phpExcel ( the problem is client side ), jquery animation it's changing width of bootstrap progress bar :) it's like $('#bar).animate({width:100px},1000); , very easy :) After i request url with location.href or native html hyperlink or via jQuery, every css change made by javascript doesn't work

Comment: js library are jquery, jquery ui, jquery cookie, bootstrap.js

Comment: Tested and work, but still not working with pdf in localhost. i created an example that generate a big pdf, tested with your code and work, but only on my hosting and not locally. I don' t know why :)  The url with pdf generator if you want to test it is http://www.next-webagency.com/TCPDF